# pvc storage capacity update

Tags: go, kubernetes, cloud

I am trying to update the pvc (persistent volume claim) size and trying to set it in pvc status.capacity.storage field. After running yaml command I can see the update in annotation but not in status.capacity.storage field.

I have updated using below code:

```
memorySize := resource.NewQuantity(int64(volumeExpansionStatus.Size)*1024*1024*1024, resource.BinarySI)
pvc.Status.Capacity[v1.ResourceStorage] = *memorySize
kube.UpdatePersistentVolumeClaim(ctx, pvc)
```

**Below is the log after execution:**

Status:PersistentVolumeClaimStatus{Phase:Bound,AccessModes:[ReadWriteOnce],***Capacity:ResourceList{storage: {{42949672960 0} {}  BinarySI},***},Conditions:[]PersistentVolumeClaimCondition{},}

**Below is the log before execution:**

Status:PersistentVolumeClaimStatus{Phase:Bound,AccessModes:[ReadWriteOnce],***Capacity:ResourceList{storage: {{21474836480 0} {} 20Gi BinarySI}***,},Conditions:[]PersistentVolumeClaimCondition{},},}

As you can see the difference 20Gi is missing in updated field. How can I get this value as no field available for it?

Comment: Does it work if you edit it using `kubectl edit pvc` ? Do you have a storage class?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes i have added storage class also. Yes its working.